# How do I type a function with parameters as `any` or `void` in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to type a function that takes in something OR nothing in typescript. How do I do that?

I've tried:

```
interface TestFn {
    (props: any | void): string
}

const thing: TestFn = (props) => 'whoo';
thing('something'); // this line is fine
thing(); // this is not okay
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use optional parameters:

```
interface TestFn {
    (props?: any): string       // <- parameters is marked as optional
}

const thing: TestFn = (props) => 'whoo';
thing('something'); // this line is fine
thing(); // this line is fine as well
```

Parameter `props` is marked with `?`, which means that the parameter is optional. You can find more information about optional parameters in [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html), section **Optional and Default Parameters**.

Comment: oh duh. I have optional parameters in my code too lol. thanks for the help. i'll accept the answer asap!